# Blue Ocean with AWS CodeCommit - is it possible to track pull requests?

Tags: git, jenkins, aws-codecommit, jenkins-blueocean

I try to configure Jenkins with Blue Ocean plugins to work with AWS CodeCommit git repository. I managed to setup the multibranching pipeline project and it is discovering branches correctly and it is building fine.

However, I added a pull request via the AWS CodeCommit user interface and it didn't show up in Jenkins. This isn't surprising, as I saw that when using GitHub or Bitbucket you need to have a dedicated plugins: https://plugins.jenkins.io/github-branch-source and https://plugins.jenkins.io/cloudbees-bitbucket-branch-source.

Is there a plugin for AWS CodeCommit? Is there any way to integrate pull request tracking?

Comment: I've found some CodeCommit related plugins, but none of these seem to cover that functionality: [codecommit-url-helper](https://plugins.jenkins.io/codecommit-url-helper), [aws-codecommit-trigger](https://plugins.jenkins.io/aws-codecommit-trigger), [aws-codecommit-jobs](https://plugins.jenkins.io/aws-codecommit-jobs), [scm-sqs](https://plugins.jenkins.io/scm-sqs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this plugin does not exist for CodeCommit today. I have passed your feature request on to the development team for further review and consideration.

Thanks again for your feedback and let me know if there are further questions on CodeCommit.

Comment: Ok, thanks for forwarding it. Is it available in some public issue tracking system? Please share the link if it is.

Comment: Unfortunately CodeCommit does not have a public issue tracking system at this time.